# Rsyslog template capture groups

Tags: elasticsearch, rsyslog

I am creating an Rsyslog template to parse apache logs into JSON in order to send to elastic search.

I am presently trying to capture the request time from the access_log but cannot seem to get my regular expression to work properly.

Rsyslog config of template constant:

```
constant(value="\",\"request_time\":\"")     property(name="msg" regex.expression="(\\[(.*)\\])" regex.type="ERE" regex.match="2")
```

I continually get "NO MATCH" from this even though the regex appears to work on the rsyslog regex test page.  If I replace regex.match with 0 I get the full timestamp but it includes the []'s which I am hoping to avoid.

Example request:

```
192.168.33.1 - - [30/Mar/2016:08:45:38 +0000] "GET /TEST HTTP/1.1" 404 281 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working by narrowing down the specific data I wanted rather than "anything in between those square braces":

```
  constant(value="\",\"request_time\":\"")     property(name="msg" regex.expression="([0-9]*\\/[a-zA-Z]*\\/[0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]{2})" regex.type="ERE" regex.match="0")
```